# Why does "hulled" mean "devoid of hulls" rather than "having hulls"?

Tags: word-meaning

I was studying the nutritional profile of sunflower seeds [here](http://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/nut-and-seed-products/3077/2) when I came across the word hulled, referencing the seeds. I had only known about the noun *hull*, and the adjective form was a first-time encounter. My first impression was that hulled meant "having hulls" since a hull is the shell of the seed, but to my surprise it means "having had the hulls removed". So I thought what if there was the word *dehull*, wouldn't that mean "remove the hulls of" and so the adjective "dehulled" could be derived? so [I looked up the word dehull](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/dehull) and it does exist with the same meaning as I predicted. Therefore, *hulled* and *dehulled* are interchangeable. So isn't it weird that *hulled* is used to mean devoid of hulls?

Comment: I'm a native UK English speaker and just came across "dehulled white lupin seeds" in an article I'm proofreading about rabbit nutrition. The term "dehulled" made me pause, as it struck me as a bit odd and I've changed it to "hulled". I ended up here by running a Google search to find out if "dehulled" actually exists, and although someone on here has commented that it does, I'll stick to what I know from experience, which is that "hulled" is the most frequently used term, at least in my working context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In English, a lot of verbs that are formed from nouns mean "remove the thing the noun refers to." Some examples are hull, shell, husk, pit, and skin. Don't use "dehull." Your source may say it's a word, but not many people will recognize it.

Note that when I buy sunflower seeds, they are usually packaged as "shelled" rather than "hulled."

Comment: Not to mention "dusted", which can mean _both_ "cleaned of dust" and "sprinkled with dust".  You really need context to know which one is meant.

Answer (score 3):

It gets a little weirder, actually. *Hulled* as the past participle of the verb *to hull* means with a hull removed. However, *hulled* can also be an adjective meaning *with a hull*, for example a *wooden-hulled ship* is a ship with a wooden hull.

Using *hull* to mean *remove a hull* may stem from the maritime term: if a ship is *hulled* it means that her hull has been breached. It appears that the word originates in OE *hulu*, meaning a husk or shell. It got the specialized meaning as it pertains to a ship in ME, whence came also the meaning of rupturing a ship's hull. I wouldn't be surprised to find that this meaning then got generalized to include the rupturing of any sort of hull; I don't find evidence of this usage (although admittedly I haven't looked very hard) prior to ME.

Comment: The etymology of hull as a noun, and probably also as a verb, predates its usage as the frame of a boat. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hull

Comment: @JavaLatte Yes, it predates as a noun. This I have mentioned as well. As for "probably also as a verb," the first meaning that I have found is the one in ME where a hull of a ship is ruptured. Of course, that doesn't mean that an earlier one doesn't exist, but given no evidence that it does, I can't see where it is "probable."

Answer (score 0):

"Hulled" is a past participle of the verb "hull," which means to remove hulls.

Comment: Correct, but you should back up your answer with a reference, for example https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hull

Comment: If it is obviously correct to a native speaker, what is the issue with a lack of an authority? It is this kind of unnecessary reliance on authority for the **obvious** that has discouraged me from continuing to comment at ELU. You apparently agree that my answer is correct. The verb "hull" means to remove the hull, as can be confirmed by any decent English dictionary. Then what more is needed to help someone learn English. We are not talking about subtle points where even a native speaker may be confused. If the OP  doubts the answer, a dictionary can confirm the answer.

Comment: @JeffMorrow  your criticism is best discussed over on [/meta](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/). but suffice it to say that if the question *can* be answered with a simple dictionary definition, then it should be closed.

Comment: FWIW, I'm in your camp; there's a little too much unnecessary reliance on authority for the obvious for my taste at times. On the other hand, I don't agree that your answer is correct. This answer doesn't appear to address the OP's question: the OP is asking why *hulled* means with hulls *removed* rather than *having* hulls. @JavaLatte appears to have missed this as well.

Comment: @BobRodes Thank you for your comment. I agree that I did not answer the exact question posed **because such questions are unanswerable.** There is no reason (other than historical) why a specific combination of phonemes has a specific meaning in a specific language. Ultimately, language is a set of arbitrary conventions. So I tried to answer what I guessed was behind the original question. Of course, I may have guessed incorrectly.

Comment: @JeffMorrow: while it may be obviously correct to a native speaker, this site is for people who are learning English. We see many answers on ELL that are factually incorrect: in this case, a reference would make it easier for people to confirm that your answer is indeed correct.

Comment: @BobRodes, I think that this answer does address the question. The OP states that hulled is an adjective: the answer explains that it is a past participle (OK yes, that's a kind of adjective, but a special kind), derived from a verb that means to remove the hull. OK, it doesn't address the question of "Why does **verb** mean removing the **noun**", but I don't think anybody can really answer that.

Comment: @JavaLatte That makes sense as a general proposition although, in this specific case, anyone who was diligent enough to check a citation would likely be diligent enough to have used an on-line dictionary in the first place. Nevertheless, yours was a helpful comment. Thank you.

Comment: I guess my feeling is that if the question can't be answered, the answer to the question is that it can't be answered. On the other hand, it would seem that joiedevivre, by providing a number of related examples, has done a better job than any of us in answering the question satisfactorily.

Comment: @BobRodes That's the reason I voted for her answer.