# What is the difference between Boner and Butcher?

Tags: meaning, difference, word-difference

In our factory the boner was talking with someone and he said he is not a butcher; hes's a boner. Can someone tell the difference between them. I searcher in dictionary but could not find it.

Comment: That must be something very specific to your industry. All the meanings I know for "boner" are sexual.

Comment: I have an idea of what you're talking about, but you should provide more details about this person. What does he do? What is his role or his duties?

Comment: I looked it up in the dictionary, and a boner could be someone who just removes the bones from a dead animal. Best guess is that a "boner" would just take out bones, while a "butcher" would cut something up into the usual types of things people eat (for example, steaks, roasts, and so on).

Comment: @Max, he's a boner in our factory and he cuts beef.

Comment: @joiedevivre Based on my cursory research, your "best guess" is pretty accurate. :)

Answer (score 2):

Googling "meat boner job description" reveals [this](https://dot-job-descriptions.careerplanner.com/BONER-MEAT.cfm). Googling "butcher job description" reveals [this](https://job-descriptions.careerplanner.com/Butchers-and-Meat-Cutters.cfm).

Basically, a boner has the specialized job of removing bones from meat. A butcher has the general responsibility of preparing wholesale meat for retail sale, which may include boning.

Comment: Nice job. I'm still wondering why someone would say what the OP quoted. Maybe it's along the lines of "I'm a nurse, not a doctor."

Comment: @joiedevivre Yes, exactly. At least that's what I think. After going over the job descriptions, a boner doesn't have any customer-facing responsibilities, while a butcher does, among other things.

Answer (score -1):

Um, I think he's a **DE-BONER**.  A butcher whose specific job it is to remove bones.  Boner might be a slang nickname.  A butcher is a person who cuts up meat.  Part of a bitcher's job is probably to de-bone.  "De-boner" would imply that he has a specialized job.

**Boner** is usually slang for an *erection*.

Comment: Well, I looked it up, and no, it isn't a slang nickname. Some people say deboner, and some say boner. For example, here is a case called [Oscar Mayer Foods Corp. v. Beef Boners and Sausage Makers Union, Local 100](https://openjurist.org/757/f2d/1291/oscar-mayer-foods-corp-v-beef-boners-and-sausage-makers-union-local-100).

Comment: Interesting that this question came up at the same time as this one: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/149701/why-does-hulled-mean-devoid-of-hulls-rather-than-having-hulls, I think they are related.

Comment: I'm sure the employees of Oscar Mayer have a lot of fun at the expense of the boners.

Comment: @Andrew https://youtu.be/aNddW2xmZp8 ... *everyone is **also** in love with the Oscar Meyer boners.*